# setResult does not work on @EActivity

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I am trying to setResult on my "Register" Button, but nothing happens:

**SignInActivity:**

Start activity for result:

```
Intent intent = RegisterActivity_.intent(this).get();
this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_USER_REGISTER);
```

On Activity Result

```
@OnActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE_USER_REGISTER)
protected void onResult(int resultCode) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        DashboardActivity_.intent(this).start();
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        this.showDialogAlert("Unexpected error", null);
}
```

**RegisterActivity:**

```
this.setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

I am using AndroidAnnotations and **I'm not using the *this.finish()*** method because it set the property ***android:noHistory="true"*** in all Activities on AndroidManifest.xml. I am also setting the parent of each activity there. Have tried to remove these settings and setResult continued without work. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using AndroidAnnotations and I'm not using the this.finish() method because it set the property android:noHistory="true"in all Activities on AndroidManifest.xml.

I think your issue is here. When you're using `startActivityForRestult`, the expected workflow is to launch a new activity, do some work and then close this activity to go back to the previous one with the result of the work. So, you can't use `android:noHistory="true"` here because it doesn't make any sense.

Also, if you look at `Activity`'s source code, you'll see that result is propagated from the `finish` method.

Comment: DayS, the problem was exactly that! I removed the `android:noHistory="true"` in the SignInActivity and RegisterActivity activities, and to complete I added the `finish` after running `setResult`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Start Activity  for Result. your code is Ok

```
Intent intent = RegisterActivity_.intent(this).get();
this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_USER_REGISTER);
```

Now Inside the Activity that you start for the result set the result status  like below code.

`setResult(resultCode);` result status possible values are like RESULT_CANCELED,RESULT_OK.etc

Activity that starts the new activity for result must override the below method and this method work when the activity that started for result finish.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the method is..

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

not onResult